# display data in time domain

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have loaded a list of data in MATLAB:

```
sample = 

            data: [120000x1 double]
           units: 'Volts'
          labels: 'Analog input'
             isi: 1
       isi_units: 'ms'
    start_sample: 0
```

Now I want to display these in time domain. How can I add a time domain?
For example, 1ms for each data; 120 seconds for 120000s

Comment: i need to plot time in x-axiz & data in y-axiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a time vector like this:

```
 t = 0:.001:120000*.001-.001;
```

or for a generic time delta and data length:

```
dt = .001;

t = 0: dt : length(data) * dt - dt;
```

Then plot the time series data:

```
plot(t,data);
```